# Not able to set the width of button with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am new in auto layout and used auto layout in scrollview i have some simple setup in UIScrollView but i don't achieve it.

First think i need to discuss is that i used auto layout in coding not in storyboard.

I have 20 button of same width and height and want to setup in UIScrollView.

But surprise my button width set as per contain insert into it. I try lots R&D but not able to find the solution

My code is following

```
 UIScrollView *sview = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    [sview setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7]];
    [sview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:sview];





    NSDictionary *dict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sview);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[sview]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-60-[sview]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
```

**setup scrollview whose width is same as view**

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dictValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"xpos":@10,@"ypos":@10,@"height":@30}];
    UIButton *previousBtn;
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        [btn setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
        [sview addSubview:btn];


        if (previousBtn == nil)
        {
            [sview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[btn]-|" options:0 metrics:dictValues views:@{@"btn":btn}]];

            [sview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(ypos)-[btn(height)]" options:0 metrics:dictValues views:@{@"btn":btn}]];
        }
        else
        {
            [sview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[btn]-|" options:0 metrics:dictValues views:@{@"btn":btn}]];//Look here i set button width same as a scrollview width but not able to do that


            [sview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousBtn]-10-[btn(height)]" options:0 metrics:dictValues views:@{@"btn":btn,@"previousBtn":previousBtn}]];
        }

        previousBtn = btn;
    }

    NSDictionary *dictBtn = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousBtn);

    [sview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[previousBtn]-|" options:0 metrics:dictValues views:dictBtn]];

    [sview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousBtn(height)]-|" options:0 metrics:dictValues views:dictBtn]];
```

Here are screenshot of this code
**In portrait**

[image]

**In Landscape**

[image]

Look in screen shot button is same of the text size not like scroll view and one more thing i am used **pure autolayout**

Comment: I have same Problem if any one have Solution please suggest. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding the constraint to the scroll view to have the same width as the view?

Comment: Sorry you can't add that constraint, but you can set equal widths from the buttons to the scrollView, that is valid. something like `[sview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[previousBtn(==sview)]-|" options:0 metrics:dictValues views:dictBtn]];`

Comment: @maty_nz Thanks for your answer but by this my button is not show proper because i need put 10 px space at start and at end.